Help me with the plotting of equilibrium solutions of a differential equation?
The following question two purpose. At first I want to solve the nonlinear first order differential equation with the help of equilibrium solutions and then want to plot the equilibrium solutions in the range $-2 \leq y \leq 6$ using some computer system. I can do the first and need help for the second part, that is, for the drawing.
The differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}=(5-y)(y+1)^2 \sin y.$$
The equilibrium points are given by $\frac{dy}{dt}=0 \Rightarrow y=5,~-1,~n \pi, ~n=0,1,2 \cdots$.
We now look at the stability of these points.
At $y=5$, $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ if $y <5$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ if $y>5$. So it is asymptotically stable, as the integral curves will approach the line $y=5$.
At $y=-1$, $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ for all $y<5$, so it unstable.
Since we need to plot in the range $-2 \leq y \leq 6$, I just consider $y=\pi$ for $n=1$, as the other values will not fall in this range. At $y=\pi$, $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ for all $y<5$. So this is also unstable solution as the integral curves will move away from the line $y=\pi$.
By hand I have plotted the following:

I need help to draw the solution through proper computer system. What are the easiest way to sketch the solutions? Which computer programming can do it perfectly?
I would like a model demonstration in Matlab or Wolfram or any online tool.

Have you tried searching for how to plot integral curves ?

@Learner: Mathematica, Maple, MatLab, Python, Julia, Online Tools are some examples

Before drawing anything, you should rethink your analysis: If $y=5+\delta$ for small $\delta>0$ implies ${dy\over dt}>0$, then $y$ is departing from the $y=5$ equilibrium point. You'll find that it's also departing if $y=5-\delta$. So $y=5$ is an unstable equilibrium point. On the other hand, if we look at $y=-1\pm\delta$, then $\sin(-1\pm\delta)\lt0$ determines the sign of $dy\over dt$, so $y=-1-\delta$ will cause departure from the $y=-1$ equilibrium point, but $y=-1+\delta$ will not do so. (I think this is still regarded as unstable, though.)

@EthanBolker, Yes I have found Geogebra but it is already built in programming. It is not clear to me how to plot the equilibrium solutions at the equilibrium points separately

@Moo, I would like to see one demonstration in Matlab or Wolfram

I posted two different variants with different levels of detail.

@Moo Your plots don't show the correct slopes. See here (which I modified from this GeoGebra app).  You can click & drag the points A-D to see the various solutions).  I'm sure the GeoGebra solutions are correct, as I also plotted them using Python.

@r.e.s., can you add the Python plot here with the code as an answer?

@Learner I only used Python for plotting the solutions -- I didn't bother to get gradient plots, since that was so much easier with GeoGebra (see my link above).

@r.e.s., that is fine. It is equally helpful to know what is the code to plot the solutions in such questions (without gradient plot)

@Learner I took the opportunity to learn about stream plots in Python, so I replaced the solution-plotter with a program for stream plots.

Using Mathematica, we an do these variants.
Here is a direction field plot. The command is
  StreamPlot[{1,(5-y)(y+1)^2Sin[y]},{t,-2Pi,2Pi},{y,-2Pi,2Pi}]


As a point of comparison, here is a vector field plot.

Here is the $-1$ variant you asked for - compare to the above.

Here is one with a huge number of points. The command is
  LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{1,(5-y)(y+1)^2Sin[y]},{"noise",500,500}},{t,-2Pi,2Pi},{y,-2Pi,2Pi},ColorFunction->"NeonColors",LightingAngle->0,Frame->False]


Compare them.

Can you write here the codes please? I need to learn it

Your plot does not show the correct slopes. See my comment to the OP, and also here (which I modified from this GeoGebra app -- you can click & drag the points A-D to see the various solutions).

@Moo, I think your figure is fine to learn as beginner of such questions. I think in my hand plot, I missed the $y=0$ solution, otherwise it matches with your plotting.

A direction field plot is supposed to show the slopes, but your plot clearly doesn't do that.  (It's not clear to me how the "vector field" it is showing relates to the slopes.)

@Moo, you have plotted the vector field ${1, (5-y)(y+1)^2 \sin (y)}$, however the vector field in the question should be ${-1, (5-y)(y+1)^2 \sin (y)}$. Would it make a difference in the slope? One more think, can I use Mathematica software in online with installing it in my computer?

@Moo, I just opened a cloud account in Mathematica. Does the basic plan (free of cost) work? Or I have to upgrade the plan?

How do you explain the incorrect slopes in all of your plots (including both $\pm 1$ variants)? For example, the flows around $y=5$ all have arrows pointing towards $y=5$, but they should all be pointed away, as it's an unstable equilibrium point.  This is shown by the analysis I gave in my comment to the OP, and is confirmed in the results of both the GeoGebra and Python programs.

Oh, I made a mistake we I drew them and wrote $(y-5)$ instead of $(5-y)$.  I will update the figures to correct this.

@Learner: I have corrected the errors.

@r.e.s.: All images have been corrected.

@Moo I found something relevant in this posting on the Mathematica website. Concerning the use of arrows in VectorPlot, "this style is misleading and should be avoided, as the arrows generally do not point in the direction of the solution curves as they are traced out" -- perhaps there is a similar issue with Mathematica's StreamPlot?

Maybe there is a bug, but it sees to align correctly with your image. At least now I am drawing the correct direction field and vector plot - given any limitations it may have.

Per the OP's request, here is a Python program that plots the slope field ("stream plot") of the differential equation (the relevant parameters are explained here):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def dydt(y, t):
    return (5-y) * (y+1)**2 * np.sin(y)

# Create mesh points
npts = 20
t, y = np.linspace(0, 1, npts), np.linspace(-7, 7, npts)
T, Y = np.meshgrid(t, y)

# At each mesh point, create a unit vector with correct slope
dy = dydt(Y, T); dt = np.ones(dy.shape)
norm = np.sqrt(T**2 + Y**2) 
dyu, dtu = dy/norm, dt/norm

# Plot
plt.subplots(figsize=(7,5))
plt.streamplot(T, Y, dtu, dyu, linewidth=.5, arrowsize=.7, density=[2])
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.yticks(np.arange(-7, 8, 1))
plt.title(r"$Stream\ Plot\ for\ \ y'=(5-y)(y+1)^2\sin(y)$")



I copied your code and compiled in some online python editor, but it is giving error. Where are running your code?

@Learner It runs without error in both a Jupyter/Python notebook and also in my Spyder IDE. You can also try it online here.

yes it is working there. However, I was trying in "onecompiler" editor here, but not working. Can you check once here?

@Learner Python is designed to be used by importing various packages of external code as needed. Matplotlib is a major one of them, and is freely available, but the "onecompiler" site doesn't seem to provide it for import; hence, the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'".

finally could you again add the solution sketch without gradient plot, as you did in the previous post? Maybe this will be helpful in future

@Learner You can copy that from the edit history: just click where it says "edited xxx hours ago" at the end of my post, then scroll to the bottom to see the first version of my answer.
